# Java : divide the screen

Tags: java, swing, layout, grid-layout

I try to do a simple swing window, but with the layout it's not easy... 
I mean I just want a window with 3 panels :

- header with 20% of window in height
- content with 60% of window in height
- footer with 20% of window in height

But I can't succeed to have what I want. I used a gridLayout(3,1) but I can't specify the height.

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements Serializable  {
private JPanel _header;
private JPanel _content;
private JPanel _footer;

public Window() {
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3,1);
    setLayout(grid);

    _header = new JPanel();
    _header.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    getContentPane().add(_header);

    _content = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(_content, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    getContentPane().add(jsp);

    _footer = new JPanel();
    _footer.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    getContentPane().add(_footer);
    pack();
    validate();

    setTitle("Chat client");
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

Can you help me ? 
Best regards

Comment: What about the other  40%?

Comment: What about the other 40%?

Comment: Ninja'd by *two seconds* with an *exactly identical comment*?

Comment: `GridLayout` will give you an even 3 way split

Comment: Sorry my mistakes ><, I want an window like : 20%, 60% and 20%.

Comment: @immibis Great minds ;) ....

Comment: Just be thankful this comment section didn't end up with 10 or 20 people posting "What about the other 40%?" (with the last 7 or 17 being well aware that it was already posted several times)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` is capable of dividing vertical or horizontal space proportionally.

Here's an example that displays a red `JPanel` in the top 20% of a window, a green `JPanel` in the middle 60%, and a blue `JPanel` in the bottom 20%:

```
    JFrame window = new JFrame();

    window.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    JPanel top = new JPanel(), middle = new JPanel(), bottom = new JPanel();
    top.setBackground(Color.red);
    middle.setBackground(Color.green);
    bottom.setBackground(Color.blue);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    // we want the layout to stretch the components in both directions
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    // if the total X weight is 0, then it won't stretch horizontally.
    // It doesn't matter what the weight actually is, as long as it's not 0,
    // because the grid is only one component wide
    c.weightx = 1; 

    // Vertical space is divided in proportion to the Y weights of the components
    c.weighty = 0.2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    window.add(top, c);
    // It's fine to reuse the constraints object; add makes a copy.
    c.weighty = 0.6;
    c.gridy = 1;
    window.add(middle, c);
    c.weighty = 0.2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    window.add(bottom, c);


    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend against reusing the same GridBagConstraints object you can end up with some very difficult-to-understand brittle code.

Comment: @Adam As opposed to difficult-to-understand code that calls the 11-argument constructor? Really, any grid-layout-based code is hard to understand without drawing a diagram.

Comment: @Adam Yeah, but it saves against having to retype common properties each time :P

Comment: I'm not saying 11 arg constructor is good, but is less bad in my eyes, from working on large swing based projects for years...

Comment: i'd just like to know, how would one do this within a main JPanel instead of  a JFrame? i tried to do something very similar inside a jpanel and it didn't seem to work!

Comment: @NatalieKalos You should be able to do exactly the same thing, except that instead of a JFrame you use a JPanel (of course).

Comment: @user253751 Thank you for your simple and explanatory answer! It was hard to find an explanation this simple!

Answer (score 3):

GridLayout always spaces evenly. You could instead use GridBagLayout, the most evil of all the Java layout managers. I've given them "weights" of 20, 60, 20 so you can see which values are which. You can just as easily use 2, 6, 2, it doesn't matter it's just a ratio. Look at the [GridBagLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more info.

Example

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements Serializable {
    private JPanel _header;
    private JPanel _content;
    private JPanel _footer;

    public Window() {
        GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(grid);

        _header = new JPanel();
        _header.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        // <=== add with constraints here
        getContentPane().add(_header, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 20, GridBagConstraints.BASELINE, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

        _content = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(_content, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        // <=== add with constraints here
        getContentPane().add(jsp, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, GridBagConstraints.BASELINE, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

        _footer = new JPanel();
        _footer.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        // <=== add with constraints here
        getContentPane().add(_footer, new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, GridBagConstraints.BASELINE, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        pack();
        validate();

        setTitle("Chat client");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Window();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Screenshot

[image: Your code fixed]